# Returning TopoJSON from server compressed

Tags: geojson, topojson, design

I am using TopoJSON Server for my geo Spatial project.

By executing the geo2topo (version 3.0) conversion from GeoJSON to TopoJSON on the server side back to the caller of an endpoint that normally returns GeoJSON.

However, I noticed that some TopoJSON files are the same size as the GeoJSON.

If I should be compressing the responses, then what compress method (gzip?) should I use?

Comment: compression should really be handled as a negotiation between the server and client